# Sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded data with restclient

Tags: http, restclient

When I use restclient with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, restclient sends newlines with the data.

For example:

```
POST :domain/thing
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data=foobar
```

The endpoint receives a form with the value `'data': 'foobar\n'`.

I could modify `require-final-newline` such that the last query in the file would work properly, but since requests are separated by comment lines, I still get the extra newlines for all preceding requests.

How can I get restclient to pass the forms correctly?

Comment: interesting because talking about Restful API over HTTP, the most popular content-types I met are application/xml & application/json. Browsing the [examples](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pashky/restclient.el/master/examples/httpbin) I did not see anything related to application/x-www-form-urlencoded :(

Comment: This is being investiguated at https://github.com/pashky/restclient.el/issues/71

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version, if you make sure that each of your requests has a comment line immediately succeeding it, then the forms will be passed correctly.

For example, the following code will send `'data':'foobar'`, with no extra newline. The content length received by `netcat` is exactly 11, which was what we wanted.

```
POST :domain/thing
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data=foobar
#
```

The block below, on the other hand, returns `'data': 'foobar\n'` with a content length of 12.

```
POST :domain/thing
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data=foobar

#
```

Comment: you can also append a dummy formparam to "catch" the newline.